# Is it possible to set background image for NSToolbar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

I am a new Mac developer and I have started to learn Cocoa. In my sample application I want to add a background image to my NSToolbar as a theme for my application and I want that image to be the full size of the toolbar. But i have checked and didn't get a solution. I want to know if it is really a possible thing.

Thanks and regards,

Mac 66

Comment: It seems your keyboard type in CAPITAL latter only

Comment: I just fixed it (the title, that is, not the broken keyboard ;-)).

Comment: Why the down-vote? It's a perfectly valid question (and nowhere near as annoying now that the caps-lock issue has been fixed :-D). +1 to counteract.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to do this. You would need to do some "evil" things with private API or create your own toolbar mechanism. If you don't need things like item overflow, user customization, etc. then it might be easier/cleaner just to use standard buttons in the top margin of the window.