# Set background image NSToolbar

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am relatively new to OS X app development and I'm wondering if it possible to put a background image to a NSToolbar, such as in Game Center.app or Calender.app(iCal.app)? I have looked around and can't find anything on here or on google. It occured to me that there might not be a public API and it might be private. My app will not be submitted to Apple's Mac App Store, so I am able to use private APIs(if necessary). If anybody knows the API, I would be more than grateful! Thank you so much

~ Confused Mac Developer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set background image for NSToolbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397667/is-it-possible-to-set-background-image-for-nstoolbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [AlteringTheAppearanceOfNSToolbar](http://cocoadev.com/AlteringTheAppearanceOfNSToolbar) link. Hope helpful.